# How to reload Backbone app?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, chaplinjs

I have Backbone app (also using Chaplin.js on top of Backbone) and it works correctly with pushState. At some point I want to detect that app code is changed and reload page (reload app code). The problem is that when user is in '/some/path' I would like to reload backbone app and make it point to '/'. So far I tried:

when users is in `/some/path` -> `location.reload()` -> it reloads app but still in `'/some/path'`

when users is in `/some/path` -> `location.href = location.origin` -> it reloads app but still in `'/some/path'`

How I can just reload app in `/` path (and clearHistory) ?

---

This is solved - use `window.location = '/'`

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly but you can try with this in your route `window.location.replace('#'); window.location.reload();`.

Comment: Can't you do `window.location = '/';`?

Comment: it does not work - it reloads page but still when app is loaded it is redirected to `/some/path` - I guess this is because of `pushState` - when `pushState` is used there isnt `#` in address

Comment: @user606521 I posted it as an answer so others in your situation can find it. I originally posted it as a comment because I thought it was not the actual answer. I'm glad I could help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `window.location = '/';`

This will redirect the user to the starting point of your application.